# SQL LINQ Lambda for inner join to select specific column

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I am trying to convert the following SQL query to lambda syntax in order to get the result directly into a list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Venue.venueAddress
FROM Venue
INNER JOIN Event
ON Venue.venueName = Event.venueName
```

What I have now is the following:

```
List<String> listOfCities;

    listOfCities = db.Venue.Join(db.Event,
                   venue => venue.venueName, 
                   ev => ev.venueName, 
               (venue, ev) => new { Venue = venue, Event = ev})
                  .Where(venueAndev => venueAndev.Venue.venueAddress).ToList();
```

This is a solution from another problem I tried to convert into my problem which obviously doesn't work since I don't get the lambda syntax (which I am brand new to as of today). Hours of google didn't help, maybe someone here can?

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes! I am using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> listOfCities = db.Venue.Join(db.Event,
                               venue => venue.venueName, 
                               ev => ev.venueName, 
                               (venue, ev) => venue.venueAddress)
                               .Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use lambda syntax:

```
 List<string> listOfCities = (from v in db.Venue
                              join e in db.Event on v.venuename equals e.venuename
                              select v.venueaddress).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: another question would be if theres a foreign key over that field and what the relation between the two tables are. db.Venue.Where(v=> v.Event.Any()).Select(v=> v.venueaddress).Distinct().ToList() might work also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<String> listOfCities;  

listOfCities = db.Venue.Join(db.Event,
    venue => venue.venueName, 
    ev => ev.venueName, 
    (venue, ev) => venue.venueAddress)
    .Distinct().ToList();
```

I tested in my computer, and it worked.
The TResult returned for the 3rd lambda function `(venue, ev) => venue.venueAddress)`, is actually the object element in the reterned list.
I added this `.Distinct()` before the `.ToList()` to ask for a list with distinct elements.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that now, lambda can be a bit tricky. Thank you for your help!